# RaspberryPi AWS - IoT cert problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, iot

I am trying to connect from my RaspPi to AWS IoT.
I am getting the info as below.

"Unable to verify the server's certificate. Either it is invalid,
    or you didn't set ca_file or ca_path to an appropriate value."

My settings are:

```
#define AWS_IOT_MQTT_HOST              "xxxx.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" 
#define AWS_IOT_MQTT_PORT              443 
#define AWS_IOT_MQTT_CLIENT_ID         "RaspberryPi" 
#define AWS_IOT_MY_THING_NAME          "RaspberryPi" 
#define AWS_IOT_ROOT_CA_FILENAME       "AmazonRootCA2.pem" 
#define AWS_IOT_CERTIFICATE_FILENAME   "xxx-certificate.pem.crt" 
#define AWS_IOT_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME   "xxx-private.pem.key"
```

I do not know which RootCA I should put and where to find it.
When I create IoT certificates I have two (prv/pub) keys and "a cert for this thing".
Please let me know how to solve it.

MW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the first certificate "RSA 2048 bit key: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary G5 root CA certificate" from:

[AWS link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/managing-device-certs.html#server-authentication)

started to work.

mw